# In Meteor autoform, how to update a collection from a table row?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

How can I implement the table in the autoform demo http://autoform.meteor.com/updateaf?

It only has code for the update form, but not the clickable table. I'd like to know how the clickable table is linked to the update form. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the table is open source and available here: https://github.com/aldeed/autoform-demo/tree/master/client/views/updateaf

The (relevant html):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each people}}
        <tr class="person-row {{#if isSelectedPerson}}selected{{/if}}">
          <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{age}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The autoform:

```
{{#autoForm id="afUpdateDemo" type=formType collection=Collections.People doc=selectedPersonDoc autosave=autoSaveMode}}
        {{> afQuickField name="firstName"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="lastName"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="age"}}
        {{#unless autoSaveMode}}
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="{{disableButtons}}">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" disabled="{{disableButtons}}">Reset Form</button>
        </div>
        {{/unless}}
      {{/autoForm}}
```

It looks like there's two way databinding involved, its fairly easy to customise to your own need.

The js is a bit lengthy to post here, everything in here is relevant: https://github.com/aldeed/autoform-demo/blob/master/client/views/updateaf/updateaf.js

Comment: Thanks for answering. Appreciate it.

Comment: it all boils down to the concept of "data context", and this is an excellent blog explaining this: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/